# Kafka Streams Transform Method and stream timestamp

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

`ProcessorContext.timestamp()` Java Doc suggests it will only return the stream time if triggered in a punctuate call - but not when handling a message in the transform method:

> Returns the current timestamp. If it is triggered while processing a
> record streamed from the source processor, timestamp is defined as the
> timestamp of the current input record; the timestamp is extracted from
> ConsumerRecord by TimestampExtractor. If it is triggered while
> processing a record generated not from the source processor (for
> example, if this method is invoked from the punctuate call), timestamp
> is defined as the current task's stream time, which is defined as the
> smallest among all its input stream partition timestamps.

So is there a way for the transform method to be aware of the stream time? I need to be able to detect the lateness of messages compared to the stream time and handle then appropriately.
Many thanks

Comment: You can implement your own `TimestampExtractor` to use `System.getCurrentMillis()`, for example, if that is what you mean by "stream time"

Comment: Hi - no we use event time, and we extract a field in the message to determine stream time. The problem is that internally stream time only increments (which is good) but when we receive an old out of order message, I need to know the internal stream time to decide how to handle the out of order message..